# Permission denied error while save index.php file?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

When we save `index.php` file on FileZilla it shows an error:

> Error:  /home/devratnacricket/public_html/admin/index.php: open for
>   write: permission denied Error:   File transfer failed

How can we save file on FileZilla successfully?

Comment: Are you uploading file on server?

Comment: Your FTP user account doesn't have write rights in that folder.

Comment: yes, I am uploading file on server

Comment: Try by first giving permission to that file to 777 and then try to edit and make some changes and try again. Or may be some thing with super user access permission restrictions

Comment: When I give permission i.e 777 to file it shows another error

Comment: Error:  set attrs for /home/devratnacricket/public_html/admin: permission denied

Comment: @samorten You can't add permission with an account that is not admin. Use root if you're the admin, or contact with the admin in other case.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your account can't save in the specified folder anything because of permission. Try it with another account that has got permission to write in that field.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have permission. By default the permission for the file is 644 can you please check if it set to 644 if not then right click on the file and change the permission.

If it has the right permission then check your account permission and set it or change your account which have all the permissions